# el.scroll is not function (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a code:

```
document.getElementById("slider").scroll(100,0);
```

On FF is working, but no Chrome. I don't know why. I am searching google to find issue. Only I found is a resolve problem using jQuery. Of course used one function this libary is... stupid.

So, Is it possible to solve differently or replaced with another function?

CSS class:

```
.

overflow_slider{
height:200px;
background-color:silver;
margin-top:25px;
overflow: hidden;
position:relative;
width:80%;
margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `scrollTop` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Note that you set this as a property, not a function call.

Answer (score 0):

overflow: hidden; disable the possibility to scroll element

use:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

if you want hide the scrollbar use in your style.css:

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.scrollbar {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Chrome has:

element.scrollHeight, element.scrollIntoView, element.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded, element.scrollLeft, element.scrollTop, element.scrollWidth.

Choose one.

Assuming you want to scroll 100 pixels down, you would do something like:

```
element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + 100;
```

Comment: Then just use element.scrollLeft.